# Has there ever been a video game based on Flash Gordon?

Tags: video-games, flash-gordon

None are listed on Wikipedia.  I'm not talking about pinball games with a Flash Gordon theme; I've seen those.  I mean a game where you get to be Flash, or ally with him, or be on his team or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is, indeed a video game based on  the comic version of Flash Gordon which was published in 1986 [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon_%28video_game%29).

There was also a video game based on the movie [released in 1983](http://flashgordon.wikia.com/wiki/Flash_Gordon_%28video_game%29).

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.  For some reason, Wikipedia's Flash Gordon (video game) entry isn't referenced on the main Flash Gordon wikipedia page along with all the other adaptations of the comic strip.  (Or it wasn't 3 hours ago.)

Comment: In a similar vein, you may want to check out Buck Rogers: Countdown to Doomsday for the Sega Genesis & IBM/PC. It was based on the original character rather than the TV show, and is very close in nature to Flash Gordon. The game is a space-based RPG where you build out your team and fulfill missions on planets or in space.

Answer (score 6):

**The Flash Gordon video game was created for the Atari 2600 in 1983 by 20th Century Fox games.**

[image]

Loosely (and I do mean loosely) based on the 1980 [Flash Gordon film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon_%28film%29) starring Sam J. JOnes, Timothy Dalton and Max Von Sydow, with the movie soundtrack by Queen.

The gameplay which looks suspiciously like the better known game [Defender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defender_%28video_game%29) consists of moving through a mini map maze and defeating 8 bit enemies who flash and mostly die. The player also has to rescue men from each area of the map. (Just like Defender...)

[image]

Comment: Glad I wasn't the only one to think of Defender when I saw those screenshots.